# How would I default visibility of a button to false if binding is null in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, binding, xamarin.forms

Apparantly in Xamarin forms there isn't an option to use FallbackValue or TargetNullValue, how could I use a converter to accomplish the task?

I'm looking to have visibility default to null if the data binding object is null.

Comment: The entire binding context would be null?

Comment: Yeah, if the context itself is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NullConverter.cs

```
public class NullConverter : IMarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object IsNullValue { get; set; }

    public object IsNotNullValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? IsNullValue : IsNotNullValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Entry Text="{Binding WhateverProperty}" />
<Button IsVisible="{Binding WhateverProperty, Converter={local:NullConverter IsNullValue=False, IsNotNullValue=True}}" />
```

For my testing, `WhateverProperty` was a string that was originally set to null, whenever I update the `Entry`, the button shows up. Of course, you can use it with any type of property.